# How to make universal text size for display in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use `TextViews` in horizontal position (3 column `GridLayout`). Text sharing same width space (similar to layout_weight in `LinearLayout`). Each `TextView` has size `14sp`. Problem is that on `Huawei P20` and `Xiami Mi`, text doesn`t fit to display width(3 dots at the end of line or last word is missing entirely). Some texts are locked to 2 lines but on these phones they need 3 lines to fit. I thought that sp is universal metric and it should look the same on each display and resize text properly based on display density.

Why is it not working on those phones?

GridLayout(2x3) example:

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
            android:text="@string/text1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/changeableText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
            android:text="--"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
            android:text="@string/text2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/changeableText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
            android:text="--"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
            android:text="@string/text3"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/changeableText3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:lines="2"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
            android:text="--"/>

    </GridLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add code of your layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting `autoSizeTextType` to `uniform`. Using `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` lets you to set fixed width or height for your `TextView`. 
Here is sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview).

Comment: I Totaly forgot about `Autosizing TextViews` , your answer looks better than mine. +1 for me, have a nice day.

Comment: Is this working in API 23 (Android 6.0) ? Because it is my minSDK

Comment: Yes @martin1337. It works with API level 14 and higher.

Comment: This makes my textviews so big thats I see only 2 letters in column. Its like 40sp or higher. It should be same for each display. Im working on design from App in zeplin. There are specified sizes for each textview in sp how it should be.

Comment: @martin1337 you can set minimum and maximum text size using  `app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"` and `app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"`. Make sure you change values according to your needs.

Comment: These min and max commands are not working for Android 23. Min to work is 26 according to Android Studio

Comment: @martin1337 make sure you use `app:` prefix not `android:`. Like this: `app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for scalable size unit for texts, if that's the case you could use [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp)

> An android SDK that provides a new size unit - ssp (scalable sp). This size unit scales with the screen size based on the sp size unit (for texts). It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.
>
> This is the sibling of the [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) size unit that should be used for non text views.

Its really simple to use, just add the dependency to the gradle:

```
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
```

And add this attribute (for example) to your textViews:

```
android:textSize="@dimen/_22ssp"
```

You can also check [ssp_example.xml](https://github.com/intuit/ssp/blob/master/ssp-android/src/main/res/layout/ssp_example.xml)